# Python: How to return value in another cell from the same row if condition meet

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

def value2(df):
if df['condition'] == '-1':
return df['value']
else:
return 0

Data['value2']=Data.apply(value2, axis=1)

Here is my original table Data:

```
 id condition value
 1  1         10
 2  0         5
 3  -1        20
```

Here is the desire output:

```
 id condition value value2
 1  1         10    0
 2  0         5     0
 3  -1        20    20
```

Could someone help me fix the code? thank you!

Comment: I also try Data['value2']=np.where(Data['condition'].eq(-1), Data['value'],0). There is not error but the output not as desire.

Comment: actually it works when I check if condition == 0, but fail when condition == 1 or -1

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done simply with `np.where` instead of creating a new function. You can use `ge(0)` to evaluate values greater than & equal to zero.

```
df['value2'] = np.where(df['condition'].ge(0),0,df['value'])
```